# Is it possible to show a div on click using the :active selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to show a `div` on `click`. The goal is to use **pure CSS** only, no jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jV5aa/ Kind of.

Comment: Edited my answer, but realised that you might not need any help with this question anymore. Anyway, hope it helps!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6jdUW/5/)**</kbd>

Consider that you want something like this:

[image]

---

We write our markup as simple as possible. One element for `container`, one element for our `link` and one another element for `popup`:

```
<!-- [container] -->
<div class="link-with-popup">

    <!-- link -->
    <div class="link">CSS</div>

    <!-- [popup] -->
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="box">CSS Description</div>
    </div>
    <!-- [/popup] -->

</div>
<!-- [/container] -->
```

Here is our layer structure in picture:

[image]

---

### CONTAINER

Let's write CSS for our container.

```
.link-with-popup {
    /* for visualizing */
    background: yellow;

    /* we need relative, because childs are absolute */
    position: relative;

    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

- `[!]` Note that we make our container `relative`. Because the children will be in `absolute` mode.

[image]

---

### LINK

We create our `link` as an absolute element from left, just as shown in the figure above.

```
.link {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[image]

---

### POPUP

The dimention of `popup` element is **same** as the container, so we set all `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` properties to `0`.

```
.popup {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: green;
        z-index: 20;
    }
```

- `[!]` Note that `z-index` of `popup` element must be greater than `link` element.

[image]

```
.popup {
        /* we won't show the popup yet */
        display: none;
}
```

By now, we'll get this result ([check it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6jdUW/)):

[image]

---

Now we want the `click` for our link. This must be done with `:active` pseudo selector in CSS. But how we must show the `poup`? We have to get the **next sibling** element by the `link`. We use the `+` selector in CSS:

```
.link:active + .popup {
    display: block;
}
```

See the result on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6jdUW/1/). But the problem is that when user realize the mouse, the popup will disappear (as it `display` is set to `none`).
So we set the `:hover` rule for the `popup` and make it `block`.

```
.popup:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6jdUW/2/). Now we get close enough. The only issue that the `popup` element, **hide** our `link`.
But it doesn't matter, because we won't set `background` for our `popup` (it will be `transparent`).

---

### TEXT

For wanted `text` in `popup` element, we set this rules:

```
.popup .box {
    position: absolute;

    /* note that we make a gap from left to don't hide the link */
    left: 130px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #505050;
}
```

Check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6jdUW/3/). Now we have all things that we need.

[image]

---

Now it's time to make our `popup` element `transparent` (by setting the `background` as `transparent` or simply remove the `background: green;` rule):

```
.popup {
    background: transparent;
}
```

[image]

---

And here is the final [jsFiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6jdUW/4/). And if you add some extra CSS to it, it can be more stylish. [Something like this that I've created.](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6jdUW/5/)

Some important note to memorize:

- In the final result, there is a gap between the `link` (blue one) and the `popup` (gray one). But the fact is that the gray element is not our `popup`. It's a child of `popup` and our popup is an 100% width and height element on the container.

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6jdUW/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: A very detailed and helpful explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the :target property (only works in moderns browsers).

Here's a qucik [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vhzve/) where I've hidden the div by applying `opacity: 0;` and the when you click the link the div changes to `opacity: 1;` The link and the div are matched using a hash in the url.

Here's the code from my example.

HTML

```
<a href="#pop">Click me</a>
<br />
<div id="pop"></div>
```

CSS

```
#pop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}

#pop:target {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

There are some side effects though. The browser will jump/scroll down (not sure if it's possible to prevent this?) to the matched div and since we are using a hash in the url it will effect the browser history and, as mentioned above, it only works in modern browsers.

**EDIT** If you want to look into other hack/tricks for pure CSS click events, this is a good post - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/