# how to make dropdown menu using html & css

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm trying to create html menu holding a login form, So when I expand the menu, a login form appears, the problem is when I click on the form to write the username or password, the menu collapses automatically and the login form disappears before I write anything inside it

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPAao.jpg) is an image of my menu and form in it.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">   
      <span>LogIn</span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
          Username<input type="text" id="UN"><br/>
          password<input type="text" id="pass"><br/>
          <input type="submit" id="login" value="login">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>​</div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery if needed -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function WTF() {
      window.location.href = "";
    }
    function DropDown(el) {
      this.dd = el;
      this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
      this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
      this.val = '';
      this.index = -1;
      this.initEvents();
    }
    DropDown.prototype = {
      initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;
        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
          return false;
        });
      }
    }
    $(function () {
      var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));
      $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: checkout my answer below it solve your problem

Comment: Drop Downs can be made only with CSS. Maybe this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331924/is-it-possible-to-show-a-div-on-click-using-the-active-selector-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is you have click event on the `wrapper` itself as well as on the `document` any click on the input fields or surrounding area executes the click on the wrapper and toggles the state according to your logic. SO any click on the elements inside bubbles up to the parent and toggles its state, that is why it collapses when you click on any input field or any other fields inside your dropdown. So one quick way is to identify the place from which event is coming from and if it is from the dropdown triggers handle it else leave it.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UHWN9/)

HTML Mark up change:- added a class called `dd` to both to identify the place of actual trigger.

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3 dd" tabindex="1"> 
    <span class="dd">LogIn</span>
```

#### Script

```
DropDown.prototype = {
      initEvents: function () {
          var obj = this;
          obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
              event.stopPropagation(); //Stop propagation
              if (event.target.className === 'dd') { //check for specfic targets
                  $(this).toggleClass('active');

              }
              return false;

          });
      }
  }
```

If you change your HTML structure to move the `.dropdown` out of the same wrapper as the trigger this issue won't happen.

Comment: @user1814595  See of this helps resolving your issue.

Comment: thank you for your help :)
I copied the code in the Fiddle as it is and pasted it and it didn't work I'm new in web design so could you tell me what should I do in details and if you have another simple code please give it to me

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/4axn4/. Key thing is in order to identify the actuall trigger i have just added a class for the elements   `<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3 dd" tabindex="1"> <span class="dd">LogIn</span>`

Comment: Use this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bhC4x/ changed the class name to trigger and see the changes.

Comment: thank you for your effort it is working now thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a very good and light weight code for this check out this it helps you

**Html code**

```
<div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">   
          <span onclick="uiDrop(this,'#topDrop', false)">LogIn</span>
          <ul class="dropdown" id="topDrop">
            <li>
              <label>Username</label> 
              <input type="text" id="UN">
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>password</label>
              <input type="text" id="pass">
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="submit" id="login" value="login">
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>​
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
function uiDrop(ths,target, auto){  
// target means that div which has to slidetoggle
// auto means target div hide  auto 

        if( $(target).is(':visible'))
            $(target).slideUp('fast');
        else
            $(target).slideDown('fast');

        $(target).mouseup(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        $(document).unbind('mouseup');  
        $(document).mouseup(function(e){
            if(auto)
                $(target).slideUp('fast');
            else
            {   
                //if($(e.target).parent(target).length==0)          
                $(target).slideUp('fast');
            }       
        });
};
```

**css**

```
.dropdown {
    display:none;
    list-style:none;
    background:#f7f7f7;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown li{
   display:block;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-3{
   position:relative; width:200px;
}
#dd span{
   display:block; 
   background:#f7f7f7; 
   height:30px; 
   line-height:30px; 
   padding:0 10px;
}
```

let me know if you have any problem while using this 
you can check this code in demo here is the link
http://visualdecoder.com/plugins/ddSlide/demo.html

Comment: thank you for your help but I didn't understand exactly what should I do ??? I copied your code and pasted it in a blank html page but It didn't work I like your demo I need to make something like this but the menu expands from the top please tell me in details what should I do because I'm new in web design Thanks in advance

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code and i'll implement it in my code let me know

Comment: thanks sire 
I'm sorry I'm still confused what should I do :$ ??
add your code to my code or make a blank html page and paste your code ??

Comment: yup please come in chat room