# appear and disappear effect for div by clicking on it

Tags: css

I can't understand how to make something like in this site: __smashingmagazine.com

If u resize the window, the search will be with a button. So... try to click on this search icon... the new div will appear with search input. and pay attention to the behavior of it: no matter what u gonna do next this div won't hide it self, but only if you click on 'x' that appear instead of search icon...  and this is pure css, right?! how this possible... 
I found this article: 
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331924/is-it-possible-to-show-a-div-on-click-using-the-active-selector-in-css)

but the behavior is very, very different... and i don't like it at all.

Any idea how to make it work like in the site above? anything would may help!

Thanks!

Comment: without JS, dude...  pure css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/we76L66h/ It uses this approach, but there are 2 buttons overlapped on top of each other. One which set the target to `#ms` and another to reset it back to `#top`. The example should set you in the right path. - The example will only change the once, but you can overlap 2 buttons with a little bit of effort. Which will achieve the same thing as the example you wanted.

Comment: N A T H! u're the man, bro! make some short answe so i'll accept it if u like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example from Smashing Magazine uses the `:target` psuedo class to change the CSS of the elements when an anchor is clicked. Here's a simplified breakdown of how they've achieved that behaviour.

The anchor is configured to set a fragment identifier in the URL, in the case of Smashing Magazine this is `#ms`. The have an anchor like this:

```
<a href="#ms">Search</a>
```

When clicked the fragment identifier is set to `#ms`, they then use this to make the search appear using the `:target` psuedo class.

```
#ms {
    display: none;
}
#ms:target {
    display: block;
}
```

When the fragment identifier is set to `#ms`, the :target styles are activated, displaying the search.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/we76L66h/

They are using `:target` with children (`#ms:target + div.example`) to also change the styling of children within the targeted element. This is how they make the button change to a "close" button when the `#ms` fragment identifier is set.